# Do I need to store personal details encrypted in firebase

Tags: firebase, security, encryption

I’m looking for some advice with regards GDPR and firebase, I’ve looked online and apparently firebase is GDPR compliant as it stores data securely during transit and the firebase servers themselves are encrypted. So if that’s the case would I even need to encrypt personal data locally before sending it to firebase?

Currently I’m encrypting all personal data but the issue is that I want to have an autocomplete function that searches for customers as the user types. Now this wouldn’t work currently as a search for ‘sha’ would not find ‘shaun’ because shaun is currently encrypted. So I’m wondering whether I even need to encrypt customer details at all as firebase is encrypted itself. The only issue is that me as a database admin can see everyone’s details in the database but surely that’s the case with all database admins in most apps as you can query the data in there to your hearts content and see everything about everyone?

As long as you are not sharing this data for any purposes outside of the apps terms and conditions this should be ok shouldn't it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about legal compliance.

Answer (score 0):

So a few things first , when you encrypt data at the DB level , any usage of that data at the application layer has to go through a level of decryption .

So in the example that you outline the autocomplete feature ideally will be served by an API and the API at the back-end will take the encrypted data through the decryption process to keep it in memory and return to the client appropriately.

Also it is not OK to assume that admin cannot go rouge , most of the data breaches and leeks happen from internal source. So it is better to keep the PII as encrypted in the DB.

Comment: thank you for your response, i'm more in favour of keeping everything encrypted on the DB level but my only concern is that with the autocomplete API is that surely I will have to get all customers from the DB before decrypting them which there could potentially be 100's. Firebase charges a read count for every document so this could incur a lot of reads if after each time the user uses the autocomplete it has to get all customers before decrypting and returning the matching customers. Am I right in my thinking here?

Comment: These optimizations can be handled at the application level where at application load the data can be read in a cache and then used for a pre determined time then reloaded in cache again. This will eliminate frequent db reads as well and make things faster.

Comment: so essentially you're getting all of the customers on application load and storing them in a cache or in memory so you don't have to search for all customers every-time you use the autocomplete API?

Comment: Depends on the data say if I am pulling  id , name and email then it should be relatively small given there ar 1000s of customers and not millions. For larger volumes we should do further optimizations.

Comment: awesome i'd only ever store id, name and email in memory and when a customer is selected it will query the DB once to get the rest of the user details

Comment: sorry to come back to this but if I am the only admin in the firebase database would it be ok to not encrypt the personal details in the Firebase DB provided that firebase itself is encrypted? I just feel it would be quicker and easier to not have to encrypt and decrypt the data

Comment: What if someone hacks into your db , essentially there is a breach then all the data is exposed to the hacker.

Comment: but wouldn't that be the same thing as someone hacking an admin account of the app itself and then getting access to all of a companies customers that way?

Comment: Obviously hacking an admin account is also a security issue and that needs to be handled separately , the database and the application are two different areas which have to be secured in there own respective best possible manner.